# Why does $a$ have to be a cluster point?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

The following definitions are from the book [Methods of Analysis](https://alansinyal.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/method-of-real-analysis.pdf) by Goldberg (pages 120-121).

> **Defintion 1**: Let $\langle x,\rho\rangle$ be a metric space and suppose $A\subseteq M$. The point $a\in M$ is called a cluster point of $A$ in $M$ if, $\forall h\gt 0,\exists x\in A$ such that $0\lt\rho(x,a)\lt h$
>
> **Definition 2**: Suppose that $\langle M_1,\rho_1\rangle$ and $\langle M_2,\rho_2\rangle$ are metric spaces, that $a\in M_1$, and that $f$ is a function whose range is contained in $M_2$ and whose domain  contains all $x\in M_1$ such that $\rho_1(a,x)\lt h$ (for some $h\gt 0$) except possibly $x=a$. ***We assume that $a$ is a cluster point of the domain of $f$.*** We say $f(x)$ approaches $L$ (where $L\in M_2$) as $x$ approaches $a$ if $\forall\epsilon\gt 0,\exists\delta\gt 0$ such that $\rho_2(f(x),L)\lt\epsilon$ if $0\lt\rho_1(x,a)\lt\delta$

In definition 2, it says we assume $a$ is a cluster point (I have bolded and italicized the part). Why do we need to assume $a$ is a cluster point? I tried to think of what would happen if $a$ was not a cluster point, and I got no where.

Comment: If $a$ is not a cluster point of the domain then there exists $h>0$ such that the inequality $\rho(x,a)<h$ is only satisfied by $a.$ So there are no $x$ approaching $a$ in the domain of $f.$

Comment: @mlf but why does it matter that there exists $h\gt 0$ such that the inequality is never satisfied? In definition 2, it does not say "all $h$".

Comment: If $a$ is not a cluster point then definition 2 reduces to $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta >0 : 0<\rho_1(x,a)<\delta\implies \rho_2(f(x),L)<\epsilon.$ But this doesn't define anything. For any $\epsilon$ you can consider $\delta=h.$ Since $0<\rho_1(x,a)<\delta$ is the empty set you can conclude whatever you like.